# Is there a Spiceworks replacement or similar for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, network-monitoring

I am looking for something like Spiceworks, but for Ubuntu. If you are not sure what Spiceworks is, it is a piece of software that runs on a computer and tells you what kinds of devices are on your network and all kinds of information about those devices.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Console-based: `nmap`. GUI: [Umit Network Scanner](http://dev.umitproject.org/projects/uns), for example.

There are [some more alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/spiceworks/?platform=linux) available, rather targeting the enterprise level.

Comment: `nmap` itself has [an excellent GUI](http://nmap.org/zenmap/), for those who want one. Furthermore, except for very niche needs, `nmap` currently tends to be at least as suitable for enterprise applications as any other port and vulnerability scanning software. (`nmap` has grown enormously in past years due to the introduction of the [Nmap Scripting Engine](http://nmap.org/6/#changes-nse) and the large number of lua scripts that have been written for it and shipped with `nmap`.)

Comment: @EliahKagan: Thank you very much for those clarifications!

Answer (score 1):

By default, there is a tool installed that can show you some network information:

[image: gnome-nettool]

This tool is `gnome-nettool`, and should provide most of what you need.

Comment: seems very limited compared to what I am looking for.

Comment: @TheX Since you say this isn't really what you're looking for, you might consider changing the accepted answer to one that is (or was) more suitable for your needs. Accepting answers that helped you most helps AskUbuntu work best for others in the community.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are looking for. Although Spiceworks (I believe) does not install on Linux it still monitors and inventories Linux computers. Are you just wanting to install it on the Linux platform?

Comment: The question is asking for software that will *do what Spiceworks does* and that will run on Ubuntu.

Answer (score -2):

You can look at [NAGIOS](http://www.nagios.org/) . this is wery simmilar to spiceworks, with a different approach. While speceworks monitors windows workstations over WMIC (server triggered) Nagios needs a tiny client-side service that sends info on monitored resourcer to nagios server.

Spiceworks and nagios can make a perfect combination for netowrk monitoring and inventory.

Comment: I don't think Nagios is capable of making an inventory of all machines in your network you haven't configured in it yet.